# Cómo definir y consultar una clase concreta usando la anotación @Union en SmallRye GraphQL

Tags: graphql, quarkus

Saludos a la comunidad de Stack Overflow,

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto Java que utiliza SmallRye GraphQL para implementar una API de consulta. En mi aplicación, tengo entidades de pregunta con diferentes tipos y propiedades. Uno de los tipos es "MultipleOptionQuestion", que contiene opciones de respuesta adicionales.

Aquí están las entidades actualizadas que estoy utilizando:

```java
package org.javapro.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.graphql.Description;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Setter
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class MultipleOptionQuestion extends Question {
    @Description("Answer options")
    String[] answerOptions;
}
```

y

```java
package org.javapro.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import io.smallrye.graphql.api.Union;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.javapro.deserializer.QuestionDeserializer;
import org.javapro.entities.QuestionType;

import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;

@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Setter
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@JsonDeserialize(using = QuestionDeserializer.class)
@Union
public class Question {
    Long questionId;
    String statement;
    boolean required;
    QuestionType type;
}
```

Mi objetivo es poder consultar las preguntas y obtener información específica de cada tipo de pregunta.

### Intentos

Para lograr esto, estoy utilizando la anotación @Union de SmallRye GraphQL en la clase Question para habilitar la herencia en el esquema sin éxito.

Aquí está la consulta GraphQL que deseo realizar:

```
query {
  questions {
    questionId
    statement
    type
    required
    ... on MultipleOptionQuestion {
      answerOptions
    }
  }
}
```

Sin embargo, no he podido lograr que la consulta funcione correctamente. No estoy seguro de cómo definir y configurar la anotación @Union en SmallRye GraphQL para que el esquema admita la consulta y devuelva los resultados esperados.

Agradecería mucho si alguien pudiera proporcionarme una guía paso a paso o un ejemplo práctico de cómo configurar correctamente la anotación @Union en SmallRye GraphQL para lograr la consulta mencionada. Además, si hay alguna otra configuración o ajuste que deba realizar para que esto funcione, por favor, háganmelo saber.

¡Muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda!